# Using regular expressions for my error log in Java

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to parse text like this:

```
'''ErrorID:  951574305
Time:     Mon Apr 25 16:01:34 CEST 2011
URL:      /documents.do
HttpCode: null
Error:    class java.lang.NullPointerException: null'''
```

Where keywords  **ErrorID: , Time: , URL:** are always the same and I need to search for them. How do I parse this text?

Comment: Seems overkill for regex... you could just split on newline then colon and trim whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your implementation supports named groups...

```
/ErrorID:\s+(?<ID>.*)\nTime:\s+(?<Time>.*)\nURL:\s+(?<URL>.*)/g
```

You can then reference them by name.

Otherwise by index

```
/ErrorID:\s+(.*)\nTime:\s+(.*)\nURL:\s+(.*)/g
```

$1 for ID, $2 for Time and $3 for URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.findall("ErrorID:\s+(.*)", text)
# ['951574305']
re.findall("Time:\s+(.*)", text)
# ['Mon Apr 25 16:01:34 CEST 2011']
re.findall("URL:\s+(.*)", text)
# ['/documents.do']
```

The regex works this way: it matches on `ErrorID:`(or other delimiter) plus some spaces, plus the rest of the string until the newline/end of string. Then it returns that "something" after the whitespace. Also, the result will be a list in which you will need the first item.
There can be other strategies of finding what you need, but I found this the most appropriate.

Comment: i need just matching regexp for this pattern , i don't care about values.

Answer (score 0):

If you require all of these in the string and don't know where they are and can use lookahead assertions:

`(?=[\S\s]*ErrorID:)(?=[\S\s]*Time:)(?=[\S\s]*URL:)`